# want to change properties of an interface using win32, wmi module

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tap, tunnel, tun

I am using `wmi module`

```
x = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(index=9)
// this index for my tap drive
```

and change properties inside the interface , it doesn't change in the interface out there

```
nic = x[0]
nic.properties['NetEnabled'] = True 
//it still gives False in the interface when i see it again
```

even I can't assign IP address, gateway and subnet mask

---

I tried

```
c = t.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_TapDrive where NetConnectionID='Local Area Connection'")
//It gives unknown object i can't deal with it
```

any help please.
I am using windows environment.

Comment: Have you try simply renaming its Caption? I found it create error